# How to manage Selenium Project Code using different package (Like page object model/Keyword driver framework)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, webdriver, qaf

Being first time user for automation I am looking for help related to organization of automation project and other related stuff. 
Can any one please share sample project with me to star with. 
I can able write script but I can not able manage code in java. Suggest me any best way any website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting new web/mobile UI test automation using selenium webdriver, you also need to choose one of the framework that provides common black-box testing needs. Even if you start with available unit testing (white-box testing)frameworks like junit/testng/jbehave/cucumber, it is not enough for black-box testing.

Automation framework provides driver management and other automation aspects. There are several frameworks available that you can use. One of the well known framework is [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/).

To start with, Checkout and refer [qaf-blank project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project) for ant + ivy or [qaf-blank-project-maven](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven) for maven.

If you are new to automation you should walk through [step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Resource and test data management is crucial for any test automation, this will managed in accordance to your framework. For example, You can have resources and test data in separate directory for each environment and configure to at the time of execution. refer [resource management](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/resource_management.html)