# How can I extract java class files from features files - cucumber?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to extract the test classes from this feature file:

```
Feature: Access seleniumframework.com website
Use selenium java with cucumber-jvm and navigate to website
Scenario: Print title, url
When I open seleniumframework website
Then I validate title and URL
```

and this is the Run class with cucumber

```
package step_definitions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:features",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report"},
    tags = {}
)
public class RunCukesTest{

}
```

Comment: Will you explain what you are trying to achieve? if you are new to automation, you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340252/how-to-manage-selenium-project-code-using-different-package-like-page-object-mo/41340539#41340539

Comment: Yes I'm new inautomation, in fact i'm trying to extract the class step definition code from the feature file

Answer (score -1):

The step definition, i.e. the translation from Gherkin to running your system is something you have to write yourself. There is no magic class generation happening that you can piggy back on.

This blog post may get you started: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/01/30/bdd-with-cucumberjvm-at-geecon-tdd-2015

Another good source could be this getting started project from the Cucumber Team: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton